# Notation in sequences of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-variables

I read in statistics books that a sequence of random variables are often written as ${X_n}$. But in all the theorems it just says $X_n$. Why is that?

And does ${X_n}$ symbolize the WHOLE sequence $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$? If so, I do not understand why one writes only $X_n$ in the theorems...

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly a sequence of random variables should be written as something like $$\{X_n:n = 1,2,\cdots\}$$ or like $$(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$$

But you know, people are sometimes lazy, so they just use $X_n$ to present both one random variable and a sequence of random variables. How to understand its meaning depends on context

Comment: Thank you for answering. Does that mean that the sequence of random variables  represents ALL the random variables in the sequence. I am confused when it says that the sequence {X_n} converges. Does that mean that ALL the random variables TOGETHER converges, or just the last X_n...?

Comment: @ErosRam When we say a sequence $\{X_n\}$convergs to $L$, we mean $\lim_{n \to +\infty}X_n = L$

Comment: So only the last random variable $X_n$?

Comment: @ErosRam Yes in the sense that it is the scalar value of $X_n$ which converges to $L$. When we talk about convergence or limit, we talk about the tendency of $X_n$ when $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: Ok. So when I have the CLT that says that the distribution of $\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt(n)}$ converges to N(0,1) as n goes to infinity, we cannot only be talking about the last $X_n$. It surely must be a sample, but I do not understand what sample... sorry...